# How to move images to the left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move my images over so they are at the center of the page. If you look at the image you can see that they are to the left of my page and they are overlapping each other. Right now they are overlapping each other so how do I get them to not overlap and that they are side by side in the center of the page below my text? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[image: My two images overlap each other]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0C133C;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav>li {
  display: Inline-block;
  padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;
}

.nav>li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0C133C;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

.clearer {
  clear: both;
}

.subnav class {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.subnav>div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0C133C;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px 30px 10px 9px;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.subnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.split {
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.centered {
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #282C41;
  color: white;
  margin-top: .5rem;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 35px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

p1 {
  font-size: 30;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
left: 100px;
}


.row .column img {
  width: 100px;
left: 50px;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
  margin-top: .5rem;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input,
select {
  position: relative;
  left: 140px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {
  background-color: #282C41;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
 margin-left: 225px; 
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Navbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>


    <subnav class="subnav subnav-light bg-light">
      <img src="universallogo.jpg" class="logo" />
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="subnav=brand" href="#">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Bonds</a>
        </a>
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Report a Claim</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About Us</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Search</a>
      </div>
    </subnav>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="split left">
      <div class="centered">
        <h1>GET YOUR LICENSE & PERMIT BONDS FAST & EASY</h1>
        <p1>We provide our Customers with a fast, easy, and secure way to get bonded. Get your Free Quote in minutes.
        </p1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <img src="Demotech.png" alt="rating" style="width:150%"> 
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="USTreasury.png" alt="treas" style="width:40%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="split right">


      <form name="form1" id="form1" action="/action_page.php">
        <select name="subject" id="subject">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your State</option>
          <option value="California">California</option>
          <option value="California">Illinois</option>
          <option value="California">Michigan</option>
          <option value="California">Ohio</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <select name="topic" id="topic">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Who is requring the bond</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <select name="chapter" id="chapter">
          <option value="" selected="selected">What jurisdiction is requring the bond</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <select name="chapter" id="chapter">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your Bond</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

      </form>

      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="text" id="date" name="startdate" placeholder="Effective Start Date">

        <br><br>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="typeemail" placeholder=" Type E-mail">
      </form>

<br><br>
<button class="button button4">GET QUOTE NOW</button>
<p> Don’t see your Bond? Click Here to Submit Request</p>
    </div>
 </div>


    

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your link tag is missing the closing `>`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having the width of your column class set to 50% since you have two items and then have them display `inline` or `inline-block`.

Comment: question and picture don't really make sense.  What are you trying to do? I don't see any images to the right

Comment: I assumed they meant the two overlapping pictures on the left lol, and that he wants them to be in the middle under the text in the dark blue part of the page.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant the images are at the left of my page and I am trying to get them centered.

Comment: centered on the page or in the left div?

Comment: there is no dark blue part of the page. voting to close until you can ask a question that makes sense

Comment: I got the images to move to the center with margin-left, but they are still overlapping each other. It almost looks like they are connected. Any idea how to separate the two?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you are intended to center the images of 'row' div inside 'split left' div.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="column">
      <img src="ss.png" alt="rating" s̶t̶y̶l̶e̶=̶"̶w̶i̶d̶t̶h̶:̶ ̶1̶5̶0̶%̶"̶ />
   </div>
   <div class="column">
      <img src="ss.png" alt="treas" s̶t̶y̶l̶e̶=̶"̶w̶i̶d̶t̶h̶:̶ ̶4̶0̶%̶"̶ />
   </div>
 </div>
```

Remove those inline style for image.

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  j̶u̶s̶t̶i̶f̶y̶-̶c̶o̶n̶t̶e̶n̶t̶:̶ ̶c̶e̶n̶t̶e̶r̶;̶
  l̶e̶f̶t̶:̶ ̶1̶0̶0̶p̶x̶;̶
}

.row .column img {
  height: 100px; /*height you needed for the image*/
  width: 100px; /*width you needed for the image*/
  l̶e̶f̶t̶:̶ ̶5̶0̶p̶x̶;̶
}
```

Do the above modification in your styles.css. Hope now the image will not be overlapped.